# Right click in eclipse is not working?

Tags: eclipse

My right click is not working in eclipse.I tried to work on servlet so i downloaded javaEE to work and used yesterday (Aug 13 2014) after i didn't used my eclipse which I am using regularly today i started working on the android in my regular eclipse.When i started working on the project my right click not working in package explorer. Also in Window --> show view showing blank.

These are the different trials i have done.

restarting the eclipse.

Change the work space.

restarted the computer.

But the problem is not solved.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Restart Eclipse with a "-clean"

Open a command prompt (click Start, Run... enter "cmd"), then go to the directory where you have Eclipse installed with "cd ", and then run "`eclipse -clean`".

Comment: Same problem for me, restarting with '-clean' did not solve it.

Comment: You may try clearing SOCKS proxy if your company using a proxy. Windows->Preferences->Network Connections->Select SOCS->Click on Clear(Make sure you have proxy server listed in it).

Answer (score 2):

I had similar symptoms recently. Turned out it was caused by the Subversion server being unavailable - once that was restarted I was able to right-click. My environment was Eclipse Luna with Subclipse.

So worth checking that any connected source control systems are operational. Hope that helps.

Comment: I had the same problem with SVN as the culprit. 
 I deleted "RemoteSystemsTempFiles" folder in my workspace and then let SVN rebuild its cache, then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You may try clearing SOCKS proxy if your company using a proxy server.

> Window → Preferences → Network Connections → Select **SOCKS** → Click on
>   **Clear** (Make sure you have proxy server listed in it).

Answer (score 1):

Turn on error view in Eclipse: `Window -> Show View -> Other`. Search for `Error`

There you'll most likely find errors in the log, which will tell you which plugin prevents the menu from opening.

For example, I found:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   de.anbos.eclipse.`easyshell`.plugin.commands.DefineCommands.createContributionItems(DefineCommands.java:49)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.ContributionFactoryGenerator.compute(ContributionFactoryGenerator.java:72)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributionRecord.mergeFactoryIntoModel(ContributionRecord.java:271)

Fixing EasyShell plugin config solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, but only in the "SVN Repositories" window (so I couldn't check out anything). Using the right-click button on the keyboard worked (had to connect an external keyboard with such a button to my laptop).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with STS and I went to the STS folder where I started STS and opened eclipse.exe instead of STS and this fixed the problem. I was able to use the Right click for my project.

This fixed my problem "temporarily ONLY"

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and went to Preferences-> Network Connections and changed the Active Provider from Direct to Manual. This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem.
Later I found that I have installed one plugin name "ContextQuickies"  from market place which is causing this problem.
I have uninstalled it and restarted eclipse which solved my problem.
My environment was Eclipse Kepler.

Steps to uninstall:
Help->Install Software->Already Installed -> This will open new window from there you can Uninstall the plugin and restart.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue. I simply restarted eclipse since I had it open for days.